# Why the property in data doesnt update in setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

I want to create button to adjust/increase the props speed when my marker is moving, but in my case the speed work if the pause button clicked . what should i do if i want to click speed button and automatically update this.speed

I've declare speed prop in data and want to use in methods with `setInterval`

this is my data :

```js
data: () => ({
  speed: 1000
  });

//my methods
moveMarker () {
  this.mapLoop = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.index + 1 === (this.coordinates.length)) {
        this.isPlay = true
        clearInterval(this.mapLoop)
        new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
          .setLngLat(this.newMarker._lngLat)
          .setText('You are arrived')
          .addTo(this.map)
      }
      const el = document.createElement('div')
      el.className = 'marker'
      console.log(el)
      this.isPlay = false
      this.map.panTo(this.coordinates[this.index])
      const lat = this.coordinates[this.index][0]
      const lng = this.coordinates[this.index][1]
      this.newMarker.setLngLat([lat, lng])
      this.newMarker.addTo(this.map)
      this.index++
    }, this.speed)
  },

//trigger button function
forward () {
    this.speed -= 500
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to cancel the previous interval and re-start it with the new *speed*. For example

```js
forward () {
  clearInterval(this.mapLoop)
  this.speed -= 500
  this.moveMarker()
}
```